# ng build without node module download

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Hi Is there a way to build/run ng cli command (ng build --prod) without downloading the npm packages every time?

The production build is very slow because of this reason, I wanted to check if this download can be avoided if we not adding any new node modules and using the existing one from the node module folder.

Comment: What build environment are you using?

Comment: production environment

Comment: all packages wont be downloaded if they are already in `npm cache`

Comment: You don't need to install node modules every time unless a new package has been added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng build --prod` is not downloading any npm packages, but instead it's bundling those packages (as vendor-chunk) along with your app code.

The reason is slow in `--prod` is that because prod uses `aot` and `build optimizer` by default. All that time taken is for good cause, to bundle your code, tree shake it, uglify it...etc.

The only thing you can do in this case, is to make sure your code is not using any unnecessary 3rd party libraries, and most importantly you're using the latest `ng-cli` and Angular versions. keep up with the latest Angular updates, as the Angular Team is working very hard to make it awesome in every version they release.